# Flashing WCE7 from USB on CCWi-i.MX53 JSK, uBoot

Tags: usb, u-boot, wce

I have tried over at the digi forum, but I'm thinking that here is where all the clever people are :-)

I’m working on a CCWi-i.MX53 JSK. What I’m trying to figure out is - as you might have guessed - to flash a WCE image from an USB stick.
Based on

http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl?id=3305

and

http://www.digi.com/support/forum/40385/mx53-jsk-with-windowc-how-boot-new-wce-from-microsd-using-uboot

my best guess is to either just

```
dboot wce usb 0:1 fat wce-CCXMX53
```

or setting the U-Boot command like

```
setenv bootcmd dboot wce usb 0:1 fat wce-CCXMX53
saveenv
reboot
```

None of the methods works for me. I’m getting:

```
Unknown command 'usb' - try 'help'
command usb reset failed
```

I’m using a freshly formatted FAT32 USB stick with only the wce-CCXMX53 file on it, in either of the J10 USB plugs.

**Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!**

Sidenote: dboot usage:

```
CCWMX53 # ? dboot
dboot - Digi modules boot commands

Usage:
dboot <os> [source] [extra-args...]
 Description: Boots <os> via <source>
 Arguments:
   - os:           a partition name or one of the reserved names:
                   linux|android|wce|netos|eboot
   - [source]:     tftp (default)|flash|nfs|usb|mmc|hsmmc|sata|ram
   - [extra-args]: extra arguments depending on 'source'

      source=tftp|nfs -> [filename]
       - filename: file to transfer (required if using a partition name)

      source=usb|mmc|hsmmc|sata -> [device:part filesystem] [filename]
       - device:part: number of device and partition
       - filesystem: fat|vfat|ext2|ext3
       - filename: file to transfer

      source=ram -> [image_address] [initrd_address] [initrd_max_size]
       - image_address: address of image in RAM (default: linuxloadaddr, netosloadaddr, etc)
       - initrd_address: address of initrd image (default: loadaddr_initrd)
       - initrd_max_size: max. allowed ramdisk size (in kB) to pass to the kernel (default: kernel default)

If <os> is 'wce' the following bootargs are possible:
    cleanhive
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I don't know dboot/wce. From my bootloader experience, you may play with the following command to read file from your USB stick to memory (without actually booting - losing control):

```
# fatload usb 1:1 (loadAddress) (bootfilename)  # load your file to memory
# md (loadAddress)  #dump memory content, which you can compare with your USB file
```

Booting process primarily comprises step1- reading an executable (OS) file from media(mmc/usb) to memory; step2- prepare environment(registers, parameter data in certain memory location, even rootfs in ramdisk...); step3- jump to the entry of executable file in step1.